# JQuery isn't getting linked to HTML?

Tags: jquery, html

Why isn't my JQuery code executing?
It's all in the same folder. I have the jquery.js in the same folder as the html and css file, and jquery source is linked from Google CDN.
I just don't see what's wrong...

```css
.Header {
    height: 75px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.HeaderText {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 27px;
    top: 24px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.Body {
    background-color: darkcyan;
    height: 1200px;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: static;
}

.Box {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 110px;
    left: 30px;
    background-color: burlywood;
    font-size: 30px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
    color: white;
    z-index: 0;
}

.Menu {
    position: fixed;
    float: right;
    height: 75px;
    width: 150px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: burlywood;
    text-align: center;
}

.Menu:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menuItem {
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    float: right;
    right: 31px;
}

/* General */

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Kollektif";
    src: url(Kollektif.ttf);
}

body {
    font-family: Kollektif;
}

/* General */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"/>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Professional looking.</title>
        <meta name="#" content="#">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".Menu").click(function(){
                    $(".Menu").hide();
                });
                $(".Menu").click(function(){
                    $(".Menu").show();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="Header">
            <p class="HeaderText">Professional.</p>
            <div class="Menu">
                <p class="menuItem">Menu</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="Body">
            <div class="Box">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how does your menu know that it is opened? You tell JavaScript to open the menu on click, but also to close it.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your Jquery?

Comment: Remove the second function and it will work and do the hide. Your jquery code is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling your menu to hide *and* show on every click

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".Menu").click(function(){
                $(".Menu").hide();
            });
            $(".Menu").click(function(){
                $(".Menu").show();
            });
        });
```

Removing the show() part will effectively hide your menu. (but then you won't be able to click on it to bring it back)

Perhaps you should try the `visibility` or `opacity` css properties to hide it without actually changing its `display` property

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".Menu").click(function(){ 
    $(".Menu").toggle(); 
  });
});
```

You can use `toggle` function to serve your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You're telling jquery to hide `.Menu` and then immediately telling it to show `.Menu`

I think you want something like this:

```
if ( $(".Menu").is(":visible") ) {
  $(".Menu").hide();
} else {
  $(".Menu").show();
}
```

Of course, you have another problem because once you hide the `.Menu` class div, you lose the mechanism for showing it again.  You need to have a clickable element that doesn't hide itself to be the switch that does the hiding and showing.  Tell us more precisely what you're trying to do and perhaps we can help you code something.

Answer (score 0):

Woow I totally forgot about the .show(), didn't even pay attention to it.